# Unix Bash: How get tabs between columns using AWK command?

Tags: bash, awk, width

I've tried several ways of getting a tab space between $2 and $11 in my AWK command, but no  joy. I'm guessing it's a printf solution but I couldn't get it working.

```
FILE* fp = popen( "ps -U root -u root u | awk \"{ print \\$2, \\$11 }\"", "r");
```

Comment: What joy would a system call give?  Can't you do the same in C?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the `OFS` variable, which is by default a space, to a tab character (`\t`):

```
FILE* fp = popen( "ps -U root -u root u | awk 'BEGIN { OFS=\"\\t\" } { print $2, $11 }'", "r");
```

I changed the quotes in your example too, as when I was testing it out in my terminal it worked this way round (AWK command in the `' '`, `OFS` in the `" "`)

I removed your escapes on the `$` symbols as I don't think that they're necessary

Using your command:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main () 
{
    char buffer[256];
    FILE* fp = popen( "ps -U root -u root u | awk 'BEGIN { OFS=\"\\t\" } { print $2, $11 }'", "r");
    while (fgets(buffer, 256, fp)) {
        printf("%s", buffer);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I pasted it straight in and got:    awk: not an option: -OFS=  I wonder is my complicated string with all it's escapes messing it up? hmm

Comment: Tried your edited suggestions: awk: 1: unexpected character '''

Comment: @COOLBEANS can you post a compilable example containing this line?

Comment: The full code is part of an assignment, so I'm reluctant to post. Now it's returning nothing, but giving no errors.

Comment: Thanks for that. I didn't make it easy for you! Works a charm :-)